# Reload .profile in bash shell script (in unix)?

Tags: shell, unix, bash

I'm new to bash shell scripting, and have come across a challenge. I know I can reload my ".profile" file by just doing:

```
. .profile
```

but I'm trying to execute the same in a bash script I'm writing and it is just not working. 
Any ideas? Anything else I can provide to clarify?

Thanks

Comment: As Ignacio points out below, your script is running in a subshell. The subshell can't modify the main shell (the child process can't modify its parent). So you need to "source" the script by using the "." command (which can also be spelled as "source"). So if your script wants to, say, modify environment variables, you need to do something like "source myscript" or ". myscript" (they both mean the same thing). This will modify your main shell's environment. (Which I think is what you're trying to do, let me know if this is wrong.)

Comment: I got my answer from your question :)

Comment: Both` source .bash_profile` and `. ./.bash_profile` returns "bash: .: Is a directory"

Answer (score 254, accepted):

Try this to reload your current shell:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Comment: Do you have an alternate solution ? Because using the `source` command will run the file as a script... In worst cases, if somebody would use a variable assignment like `MyVar="$foo$MyVar"` in their bash_profile, then `source ~/.profile` would give the end result `MyVar="$foo$MyVar$MyVar"`, hence `$MyVar` would have the wrong value afterwards. (Regardless of bad practices, just ask for an alternate solution)

Answer (score 12):

A couple of issues arise when trying to reload/source ~/.profile file.
[This refers to Ubuntu linux - in some cases the details of the commands will be different]

1. Are you running this directly in terminal or in a script?
2. How do you run this in a script?

Ad. 1)

Running this directly in terminal means that there will be no subshell created. So you can use either two commands:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

or

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

In both cases this will update the environment with the contents of .profile file.

Ad 2) You can start any bash script either by calling

```
sh myscript.sh
```

or

```
. myscript.sh
```

**In the first case this will create a subshell that will not affect the environment variables of your system and they will be visible only to the subshell process. After finishing the subshell command none of the exports etc. will not be applied.
THIS IS A COMMON MISTAKE AND CAUSES A LOT OF DEVELOPERS TO LOSE A LOT OF TIME.**

In order for your changes applied in your script to have effect for the global environment the script has to be run with

```
.myscript.sh
```

command.

In order to make sure that you script is not runned in a subshel you can use this function. (Again example is for Ubuntu shell)

```
#/bin/bash

preventSubshell(){
  if [[ $_ != $0 ]]
  then
    echo "Script is being sourced"
  else
    echo "Script is a subshell - please run the script by invoking . script.sh command";
    exit 1;
  fi
}
```

I hope this clears some of the common misunderstandings! :D
Good Luck!

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
cd 
source .bash_profile
```

Comment: returns "bash: .: Is a directory"

Answer (score 4):

The bash script runs in a separate subshell. In order to make this work you will need to source this other script as well.

Comment: I'm not sure (still new to all of this) what you exactly mean by "source"-ing the other script. Could please expand a little on that.
However I have tried:

$ . ~/.profile
$ . /etc/profile

with no success. Thank you so much.

Comment: @amirrustan: Your script will need to source your `.profile` file something like this: `. $HOME/.profile` and you will need to start your script by sourcing it also. Something like `. /path/to/yourscript`

Comment: @amirrustam please read http://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-script/176788#176788

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
# .... some previous code ...
# help set exec | less
set -- 1 2 3 4 5  # fake command line arguments
exec bash --login -c '
echo $0
echo $@
echo my script continues here
' arg0 "$@"
```