# How to do Aliases in busybox

Tags: alias, busybox

I am trying to create an alias "**ll**" that would translate to "**ls -lrt**" like I'm used to.
As per general concept i should find a file named **.shrc**. In that file, i may already have default aliases . But there is no such files there .

Have tried with direct input to the console :

> alias ll='ls -al'
>           alias: not found

Please suggest if any one have any idea for this .

Answer (score 3):

Okay this question is very old, but I had the same problem. (Just installed OpenWRT on a router.)

The easiest way is to create a file with the name **.profile** in your home directory,  and add your favorite aliases. Works with Busybox 1.30.1 on my router.

*Example:*

```
alias vi='/usr/bin/vim'
alias cd..='cd ..'
alias la='ls -la'
alias q='exit'
```

Answer (score 0):

@user10008009 It works very good! I use your idea this way

```
cat <<EOF > $HOME/.profile
alias vi='/usr/bin/vim'
alias cd..='cd ..'
alias la='ls -la'
alias q='exit'
EOF
```

To apply new settings you can just reboot or [reload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274397/reload-profile-in-bash-shell-script-in-unix).

Comment: Perhaps note that this will overwrite any previous contents of your `.profile`. It would be safer to append with `>>` instead of `>`.

Comment: Also, `.profile` is the wrong file for interactive preferences really, as it will be loaded by noninteractive shells, too. You can wrap the interactive code in something like `case $- in *i*) : ... your code here;; esac`